# InitialCreate Migration for existing database

Tags: database, entity-framework, code-first

I've got a database created via Entity Framework code first. Then I've decided to add migrations.
First of all I'd like to add InitialCreate migration to create database for those computers that do not have my app yet. And then I want to add migrations to newer versions for all of them.
My current database structure is the same as in InitialCreate, but it still tries to execute InitialCreate on those computers, who already have my application and database. And it fails. Is there any way to tell EF code first not to start InitialCreate if database already exists and has the same structure?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this in you're configuration.cs... Hope it work for you

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
}
```

Comment: it didn't. I've read, the Enable-Migrations command creates InitialCreate migration itself. But it didn't